# Django local install on ubuntu

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to install django locally on ubuntu but cannot get it to recognize admin-django.py. I performed the subversion checkout, moved the django directory on to the python path and then created a symlink to django-admin.py. I can import django from within the python interpreter but cannot run 
    django-admin.py startproject mysite

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to give the full path to django-admin.py. Giving us the error message would help.

If your symlink is in the current directory (you don't say) then:

```
./django-admin.py
```

should work. Otherwise its

```
/usr/wherever/python/site-packages/something/django/huh/django-admin.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the django-admin.py file is executable:

```
chmod +x django-admin.py
```